# Ajax Spinner in modal dialog

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the ajax spinner in modal dialog. I have an ajax spinner already in my page in one of the ajax action for which initially I have coded it using the following code.

```
$(document)
      .ajaxStart(function () {
              $loading.show();
      })
      .ajaxStop(function () {
              $loading.hide();
});
```

But this is too generic, now I want to show the spinner in one of the modal popup and I tried using the following code

```
$('#modal_loading_div').bind("ajaxStart", function(){
  alert('In ajax Start of modal dialog');
  $modalLoading.show();
});
$('#modal_loading_div').bind("ajaxStop", function(){
  alert('In ajax Stop of modal dialog');
  $modalLoading.hide();
});
```

The above code is not called single time and control is not flowing. As an immediate tweak I tried my way doing this

```
$(document)
      .ajaxStart(function () {
          if(dialog){
              $('#delete_loading_div').show();  
          }else{
              $loading.show();
          }
      })
      .ajaxStop(function () {
          if(dialog){
              $('#delete_loading_div').hide();  
          }else{
              $loading.hide();
          }
});
```

but want to know the right way to do this. I am using the jquery-2.1.4

Comment: I wouldn't bind to it the way you are, but would call the ajaxStart on the event for the dialog "open" or create, and then call teh ajaxStop on the callback. Try that, and see if you get the correct behavior you want. I can offer code example if you would like,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not really a 'correct' way of doing this.

**As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStart() method should only be attached to document.** (https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/)

If you're binding on ajaxStart, then the code you've shared is really the only way of differentiating between whether the 'modal' or 'general' spinner should show. I imagine you have something like:

```
$('.open-modal-dlg').click(function(){
    dialog = true;
    $.ajax(...);
    ...
});
$('.close-modal-dlg').click(function(){
    dialog = false;
    ...
});
```

That's fine, as it is.

The only alternative I can see is to not use `$.ajaxStart`, and instead handle displaying the spinner on each of your AJAX calls.

```
$('.loading').show();
$.ajax(...).always(function(){
    $('.loading').hide();
});

// -- for modals...

$('.loading-modal').show();
$.ajax(...).always(function(){
    $('.loading-modal').hide();
});
```

`.ajaxStart` is a global AJAX jQuery event, so there's no way of limiting it, apart from keeping track of a separate variable yourself.